# How can I bind multiple dates to my viewmodel property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

Hi I am new to WPF and I want multiple selected dates from calendar to my property
that is in my viewmodel and the data context has been set.

Here is my View (MainWindow.xaml) file

```
<Calendar
            SelectionMode="MultipleRange"  
            DisplayDateStart="3/1/2022"
            DisplayDateEnd="3/31/2022"
            FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"
            IsTodayHighlighted="True"
            SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DateList}"        
            />
```

And I want to receive multiple selected dates by user in my (PersonViewModel.cs) viewmodel in the below property

```
namespace MVVMPractice.ViewModel
{
    public class PersonViewModel 
    {

        List<DateTime> _dateList;
        public List<DateTime> DateList
        {
            get { return _dateList; }
            set 
            { 
                _dateList = new List<DateTime>(value);
                //NotifyPropertyChanged("DateList");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: as i can remember, a Calendar can only select a single date

Comment: The selected dates are in the `SelectedDates` property. Unfortunately, this property is "read-only" and you cannot directly specify a binding in it. To transfer its value to the VM, you will have to use either Behavior or Code Behind.
The property in the VM to get this collection must be of type
`ObservableCollection<DateTime>` or `Collection<DateTime>`.